# Проблема в session (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, сессия

Добрый день. Вопрос вот какой. Передаю данные через сессию с одной страницы на другую, а в результате получается проблема вот какая.
На исходной странице задается переменная $_SESSION['name'] (на этой же странице делаю проверку и вывожу ее - все нормально). На этой же странице есть форма, которая заполняется пользователем. Туда можно вписать число. Допустим 5. Жмем на кнопку "Отправить". Обращаемся к скрипту обработчику формы. В нем из переменной $_SESSION['name'] извлекается имя, а из переменной $_POST['number'] получаем число. Записываем это все дело в БАЗУ. После это идет      unset($_SESSION['name']); 
Возвращаемся на предыдущую страницу.

Просматриваем другую страницу сайта ($_SESSION['name'] выводится соответствующей новой странице). Вводим число и жмем опять отправить. В этом случае должна быть отредактирована запись в БД, она и редактируется. НО
Должна получиться запись типа:
Имя1|Имя2
Число1|Число2
А получается 
Имя1|array
Число2|Число2
Тоесть при вводе данных, PHP думает что передан массив и это при том, что на странице ввода отображается просто переменная. Вопрос, как такое возможно? Как  вылечить?
Пример кода:
Страница ввода:

```
 session_start();
     unset($_SESSION['name']);
 $_SESSION['name'] = $nameg;
      <form action="add.php" method="post" id="data">
         <input name="number" type="text" value="1" />
      </form>
      <button type="submit" form="data">Отправить</button>
```

Файл add.php выглядит так:

```
 session_start();
 include ("cfg/cfg.php");
 mysql_set_charset("utf8");
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."';");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

      if(empty($row['id']))
      {
            $query = "INSERT INTO table
                     (username,name,number)
                                      VALUES 
                            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."',
                             '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['name'])."',
                             '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number'])."')";
      }
else 
      {
      $name = $row['name'].'|'.$_SESSION['name'];
      $number = $row['number'].'|'.$_POST['number'];
            $query = "UPDATE table SET 
                                     name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."',
                                     number = '".mysql_real_escape_string($number)."'
                     WHERE id = '".$row['id']."';";
     }
 mysql_query($query);
```

Проблема образуется на втором и последующих прохождениях.

Answer (score 1):

Из кода не видно, откуда берётся переменная `$nameg` . Возможно, стоит проверить, что приходит в переменную $nameg на этом шаге. Например, так `var_dump($nameg)`. Либо же можно просмотреть весь массив `var_dump($_SESSION)` перед формированием переменной `$name`. 
Думаю, проблема, всё-таки, в переменной `$nameg`. Нужно смотреть код, где она инициализируется и чем заполняется.

Comment: большое спасибо за наводку. $nameg - получается из базы данных, при просмотре страницы. Проще говоря, это переменная обозначает заголовок страницы. $nameg = $row['name'];. Она абсолютно нормально отображается на странице, из чего можно сделать вывод, если я не заблуждаюсь, что проблема скорее всего не в ней.

Comment: Может быть в код закралась незаметная на первый взгляд ошибка, может проблема в чём-то ином. Пути кодера неисповедимы... Нужно видеть весь листинг кода, где инициализируется переменная $nameg. Может именно перед присваиванием переменной $nameg здесь: `$_SESSION['name'] = $nameg;` сама переменная была инициализирована не так `$nameg = $row['name'];`, а так `$nameg = $row;`